# Print a string n times in C

Tags: c

Having a variable

```
h = get_int()
```

how do I print (using `printf`) this variable

```
e = " "
```

h times?
I know it may sound stupid, but I´m a rooky.

Comment: do you know what a for loop is? Do you know how to print it once? What did you try and what errors do you get?

Comment: [Find a good beginners book or tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about *loops*.

Comment: Take a look at a [textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Check out SO doc on loops here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/5151/iteration-statements-loops-for-while-do-while#t=201706091436542342575

Comment: The [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) function can do all sorts of formatting, but it cannot repeatedly format a single item a (variable) number of times.  There's a stunt you could pull with POSIX `printf()` for a fixed number of times, but not for a variable number of times, and it would be abuse of the function to use the stunt (which is `printf("%1$s%1$s%1$s", e)` to print it three times).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
For you, making a MCVE probably starts with finding a "HelloWorld" in C and playing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on C loops [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm)

```
for(int i = 0; i < h; i = i + 1 ) {
      printf("%s", e);
}
```

Comment: It's more conventional to use `; i++)` as the last term in the `for` loop control.

Comment: I agree, I was lengthening the syntax for clarity considering he is probably very new to for loops

Answer (score 0):

you probably mean printf...

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < h; i++)
  printf("%s ",e);
```

Comment: `%c` is for character while you OP wants to print a string. You need `%s`. Also, you are just using `i` to iterate, you can declare it within the `for` like that : `for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)` so it will be destroyed after leaving the loop.

Comment: @Badda you cannot insert int inside the loop, only when you compile with C99, atleast i always had this problem in C, yea should be %s instead of %c

Comment: What are you doing not using C11?  C90 is a quarter century old and 17+ years out of date (it was superseded by C99)?  You should be compiling using C11 by default.

Answer (score 0):

A while-loop would also be applicable. You can use the variable `h` as a counter. It a while loop you would first print the number and then count the variable `h` in a count-down manner until it is 0. This way you will have printed it exactly h-times

```
while(h>0){
    printf("%s", e);
    h--;
}
```

Disclaimer: this will of course change the value of h! If you depend on it to use it unchanged somewhere else then you should go for the for-loop solution

Comment: This destroys the value of `h`.  It isn't clear whether that matters, but a `for` loop using `h` as the limit is probably better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right, I wrote a disclaimer, restricting my answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you asks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *inputString(size_t size){

    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(stdin)) && ch != '\n'){
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}

int main(void){
    char *e;
    int times,i=0;

    printf("input string : ");
    e = inputString( 10);
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&times);
    for(i=0;i<times;i++)    
        printf("%s ", e);   

    free(e);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The character-reading loop seems to insist on getting a blank or newline before it exits.  That's weird.  Normally, you want a 'graphic' character (something that isn't white space).  You could do that with `" %c"` as the format and no loop.  Also, on the first iteration, `element` is uninitialized.  Don't test uninitialized variables; you don't know what's going to happen.  It's also a good idea to be consistent in layout. You had braces around the `scanf()`, but it was on the same line as the `while` — that's pretty nasty formatting. The `for` didn't have braces. I made them consistent.

Comment: I grant you the question asks about `e = " "` which could be a partial justification for looking for a blank or newline, but then you could simply have worked with `char *e = " ";` and printed that.

Comment: OP explicitly asks how to print a variable which can be written/initialised as `e= " "`. It seems that goal is not covered by your answer. The implicit question "How can I learn the very basic concepts of C?" is not answered by you either.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for information . I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A *for loop* is the typical way to count iterations, but the syntax of a *while loop* may be more clear for a beginner:

```
int count = 0;
while (count < h) {
    printf("%s", e);
    count = count + 1;
}
```